# how can i display an object's string method using javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, instance-variables

The main method is in the Calculate extends EnemyType class.
switch statement has 9 cases
nested in a while loop
each instantiating a subclass
which then constructs EnemyType. (should this be a uml diagram or something?)
void calc() method displays result in system output,
ending the switch statement,
returning to the loop in the Calculate main() method.

This class attempts to use javafx.scene.control.ComboBox; to fire the nested switch statement. i think the issue is somewhere between the descriptionpane, or the setAll() void method in the subclasses. i would like the contents of the subclass setAll() void method to display in the descriptonpane, or label or something. but as it is now only prints to the console.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    DescriptionPane D = new DescriptionPane();
    Label lbl = new Label();

    ComboBox<String> cboTypes = new ComboBox<>();
    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList
      ("Light Grineer", "Medium Grineer", "Heavy Grineer", 
              "Light Corpus", "Medium Corpus", "Heavy Corpus",
              "Light Infested", "Medium Infested", "Heavy Infested");
    cboTypes.getItems().addAll(items);
    cboTypes.setValue(items.get(0));
    cboTypes.setOnAction(e -> {

        currentIndex = items.indexOf(cboTypes.getValue());

        switch(currentIndex){
        case 1: System.out.println("LightGrineer"); new LightGrineer().setAll();
        case 2: System.out.println("MediumGrineer"); new MediumGrineer().setAll(); break;
        case 3: System.out.println("HeavyGrineer"); new HeavyGrineer().setAll(); break;
        case 4: System.out.println("LightCorpus"); new LightCorpus().setAll(); break;
        case 5: System.out.println("MediumCorpus"); new MediumCorpus().setAll(); break;
        case 6: System.out.println("HeavyCorpus"); new HeavyCorpus().setAll(); break;
        case 7: System.out.println("LightInfested"); new LightInfested().setAll(); break;
        case 8: System.out.println("MediumInfested"); new MediumInfested().setAll(); break;
        case 9: System.out.println("HeavyInfested"); new HeavyInfested().setAll(); break;

    }
      });
    VBox vBox = new VBox(20);
    vBox.getChildren().add(D);
    vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

    HBox hBox = new HBox(10);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(new Label("Choose Enemy Type: "), cboTypes);
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);


    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setBottom(hBox);
    pane.setLeft(vBox);

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 900, 400);
    primaryStage.setTitle("EnemyTypes_by_JohnRyan"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage  

}
```

Comment: "_I would like the contents ... to display in the descriptonpane_" Which line of code did you expect to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason the indices in the switch do not match the indices in the list? Furthermore is it intentional to execute 2 cases for `case 1`? How is the `setAll()` method supposed to get the reference to something, a `Label` or the `DescriptionPane`? Also why not use factory/strategy/command to avoid the switch?